# 2xArduinos, 2xDevices, I2C setup

Tags: arduino-ide, i2c, communication

Is it valid configuration using hardware I2C pins:

[image: I2c bus configuration]

Especially: can `NanoEvery` initialize communication with `DS2482`, while it is slave for `Mega2560`? Using Wire library or should I use software I2C when talking to `Mega2560` and leave `NanoEvery` as master to `DS2482`?

*Needed to use additional Nano due to long times of reading temperatures connected to DS2482 that blocks Mega controller.*

[Graph source](https://bit.ly/2OH0I4X)

Comment: why would the reading block the Mega? ATmega 4809 has "Independent Master and Slave operation– Combined (same pins) or Dual mode (separate pins)", but I don't know if the Arduino libraries support it

Comment: @Juraj firstly Nano and Mega were connected by serial, now I'm trying to combine them in one rail mounted case and save 2 pins, trying to not add new hardware.

Comment: you don't need the Nano. in Mega start the reading in sensor, do other things and later read the result from the sensor